# How to send email with attachment through SharePoint hosted app

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I want to send email with attachments in share-point hosted app,how can I do that?i tried some thing like below

```
function sendMail() {
    var mail = {
        properties: {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
            From: 'abc@mail.com',
            To: { 'results': ['pqr@mail.com'] },
            Body: 'some body',
            Subject: 'subject'
        }
    };
    var getAppWebUrlUrl = decodeURIComponent(utils.getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl").replace("#", ""));
    var urlTemplate = getAppWebUrlUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(mail),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    });

}
```

but it is without attachment. And giving error for `SP.Utilities.Utility`.

this shows me error like as below snap
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "`SP.Utilities.EmailProperties`" object has only the following available properties:

`From`, `To`, `CC`, `BCC`, `Subject`, `Body`

But unfortunately , It does not have a property for Attachments, check more at [SP.Utilities.EmailProperties object (sp.js)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246895.aspx)

In this case, you need to try to use workflow /  Object Model via c# .

**Regarding your Quest update**

this issue is related to `To` field where The recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user for security reasons.

Comment: workflow might help but this code is not working for sending simple mail,it shows (  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7HXtx.png )error

Comment: is there any other option to for this excep workflow?

Comment: are you configure outgoing mail within Sharepoint?

Comment: yes ,i did that

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint whole purpose is to manage content and eventually remove the need to float documents over emails.

Hence I would recommend upload the document into a library and sent the link over email.