# how to send email through SP hosted app without using SP.Utilities.EmailProperties

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

i want to send email using SharePoint hosted app  to receiver(not only share point user),i followed [This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189964/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-through-sharepoint-hosted-app) but it is allowed me to send mail to only SharePoint users,and when am trying to send mail to some one who is not a SharePoint user then am getting the error at  _api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail by saying bad request

> (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request))

is there any way to send email through SP-Hosted App without using SP.Utilities.EmailProperties?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot send e-mails to external E-Mail addresses via the OOB SharePoint object models. You can however as a workaround implement your own E-Mail sender service, make it available via REST, and [call this interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj163088.aspx) from your SP hosted app.