# can we send email through remote event receiver in SharePoint hosted app(on-premise)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, event-receivers, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to create a simple SharePoint hosted app which will send an email to any email id,I followed [how-to-send-email-with-attachment-through-sharepoint-hosted-app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189964/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-through-sharepoint-hosted-app) which is feasible to send mail but to SharePoint user only.

So I was thinking to use remote event receiver for this purpose if it is possible.

Comment: For remote event receivers you would need a Provider Hosted add-in, not a SharePoint Hosted. From that you can send email via SharePoint CSOM in C# or through standard .Net SMTP

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/879538/How-to-Send-Email-in-SharePoint-Provider-Hosted-Ap) to send Email and particularly refer section "Using General Email Sending Method" to send mail with attachment and to any user.
[image]